# Choosing a for loop based on if condition in Django

Tags: python, django

In Django How can I write condition for choosing one of two `for` loops?

```
{% if type == 'type_one' %}
{% for object in type_one_ojects %}
{% elif type == 'type_two' %} # this_line
{% for object in type_two_ojects %}
...
########## Given error ##########
# Invalid block tag on this_line: 'elif', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Comment: Not like that. IMHO the best way to do this is in Python code when you create the context for the template.

Comment: Such logic belongs in the view, not in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Such logic does *not* belong in a template, but in a view. Indeed, a template is concerned about *rendering logic*, not *business logic*. In the view you can check if the type is `type_one` or `type_two` and pass the set of items accordingly.

The view thus should look like:

```
def some_view(request):
    # …
    objects = type_one_objects if type == 'type_one' else type_two_objects
    context = { 'objects': objects }
    return render(request, '%name_of_template.html', context)
```

and then enumerate in the template with:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    <!-- … -->
{% endfor %}
```